# Adding a list inside 'app.config' in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

Below is my Windows Service(VB.NET) code,

```
Private Sub OnTimedEvent(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim connections As New List(Of String)()
        connections.Add("SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department),
                                RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator),
                                RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced), RTRIM(item_no), 
                                RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted)
                             FROM NOR_LABOR 
                             WHERE ID > 40006
                             ORDER BY ID;")
        connections.Add("SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department),
                    RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator),
                    RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(labor_feet_produced), RTRIM(item_no)
                FROM Setter_Labor
                WHERE ID > 219430
                ORDER BY ID ;")
        connections.Add("SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(Department), RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator),
                    RTRIM(total_labor_hrs), RTRIM(qty_produced), RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted), 
                    RTRIM(job_start), RTRIM(job_end), RTRIM(qty_ordered), RTRIM(wrapped), RTRIM(total_shift_hrs), RTRIM(check_emp), machine, RTRIM(operation_complete)
                FROM wrap_labor
                WHERE ID > 123884
                ORDER BY ID ;")
code continues.....
```

If I want to store these connections inside 'app.config' file and get those values from there how should I do that so?

I've tried doing as following but it throws me some errors

```
Error1(Underlines SELECT keyword): Missing required whitespace 
Error2(Underlines all the parameters):Missing attribute value on attribute 'trx_date', Missing attribute value on attribute 'work_order',etc.
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
      <appSettings>
        <myConnectionKeys>
          <add key="con1" value="connections.Add("SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department), RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced), RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted) FROM NOR_LABOR WHERE ID > 40006 ORDER BY ID ;")"/>
          <add key="con2" value="connections.Add("SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department), RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(labor_feet_produced), RTRIM(item_no) FROM Setter_Labor WHERE ID > 219430 ORDER BY ID ;")"/>
          <add key="con3" value="connections.Add("SELECT ID, RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(Department), RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), RTRIM(total_labor_hrs), RTRIM(qty_produced), RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted), RTRIM(job_start), RTRIM(job_end), RTRIM(qty_ordered), RTRIM(wrapped), RTRIM(total_shift_hrs), RTRIM(check_emp), machine, RTRIM(operation_complete) FROM wrap_labor WHERE ID > 123884 ORDER BY ID ;")"/>
        </myConnectionKeys>
      </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First these are not connections. That is a bad name for these strings.

Comment: You didn't show the code where the error occurs. How are you adding those values to the config file? No error happens in the code you showed.

Comment: @Mary sorry if I didn't make it clear, so in the first code you're seeing the connections which are perfectly working right now. But my goal is to transfer those connections into 'App.config' file and import them to the main code maybe like Dim list As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("con1") as you see in the bottom code section(That's my App.config file). However it's giving me those errors which I've added to the question.

Comment: If this is the line of code that causes the error then add it to your question. Use the Edit link. The most important info in the question should not be buried in comments.

Comment: Why are you calling the string variable list? It is not a list! Perhaps this is just a random name for your example but if this is the real name in your code it is misleading.

Comment: Can I ask how you went about adding those keys to the config?  Did you manually add to the xml or use the settings designer?  Structure of the xml seems a little off to me

Comment: @Hursey yes, that's what my goal is. Transferring the list(connections) as a it is(if possible as a list) to the config file. So that I won't have repetitive code inside my file and whenever I want I can call the keys from 'App.config' file. Plus I just have to edit one place if incase I have to change something in the future rather than editing multiple places. Thank you!

Comment: That’s likely your issue I’m thinking, add those settings through the settings designer.